# Dynamically create an HTML table in Express.js

Tags: express

I'm new to Node.js/Express.js and I've been reading a lot, but I confess that perhaps I'm still to stick into the PHP paradigm. I'm thinking to shift my site's server from PHP to Express.js, but there are certain issues that I still cannot figure out.

For example in PHP, if I wanted to dynamically build an enormous HTML table from an Object or Array I would simply do something like:

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
  }?>
</table>
```

How would I do that in Express.js with or without Jade?

Comment: You have multiple options from https://handlebarsjs.com https://reactjs.org/ https://vuejs.org and many more

Comment: @asosnovsky Could you kindly be more descriptive?

Comment: Express on its own does not have a way to do it, you need to either integrate a template processing framework like https://handlebarsjs.com/ or shift how you think of the application be adding a client-side view-layer like https://reactjs.org or https://vuejs.org. I think you go for handlebars, as it would be closer to how you use to work in php (with slight different syntax)

Comment: @asosnovsky Could you kindly provide here an example with `handlebarsjs` and I'd set your answer as the solution? Thank you in advance

Comment: someone made a downvote. Reasons should be provided according to guidelines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can do the same thing with *express*:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  let obj = { 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three' }

  let result = '<table>';
  for (let el in obj) {
    result += "<tr><td>" + el + "</td><td>" + obj[el] + "</td></tr>";
  }
  result += '</table>';

  res.send(result);

})
```

But it's a good idea to decouple data from view with the use of a template engine like *jade*:

index.pug:

```
table
  each value, key in data
    tr
      td #{key}
      td #{value}
```

server.js:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let obj = { 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three' }
  res.render('index', { data: obj })
})
```

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Thus in `jade` the expression `each value, key in data` fills HTML to the browser according to the `data` object which you sent in `server.js`

Comment: What I mean is that I thought it was impossible to make a 'static' `view model` be filled immensely with data from an object. Thus it's very similar when jQuery fills 'static' html. Thanks `:)`

Comment: Sure, and you can use any template engine that suits you, like _handlebars_ as suggested by asosnovsky in his comment.